# javascript fill function data from multidimensonal array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have some js code to make organizational chart. I made an array of id's, names, etc; I need to fill the js data array but i can't do it. This is the function:

```
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var passedArray = <?php echo json_encode($reeco_net); ?>;
    const jid =(passedArray[1][0]);
    const jpa =(passedArray[1][1]);
    const jav =(passedArray[1][2]);
    const jcd =(passedArray[1][3]);
    const jre=(passedArray[1][4]);
    const jno=(passedArray[1][5]);
    
    
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
    data.addRows([
    
      [{'v':`'${jre}'`, 'f':`${jno}`+ '<a href="hhh.com?thx='+jid+'"><button type="button" style="border:none;background-color: transparent;"><img class="table-avatar circular-square_v" src="../img/avatar/'+jav+'" width="40px" height="40px"></button></a>'},
       '', 'toolTip'],
      
    ]);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {'allowHtml':true});
  }
</script>
```

I need to fill `data.addRows([....])` with the data from `passedArray`. I know the "passedArray" is ok because if I replace the elements index by 1, 2, 3 etc the names will display correctly, but how can I loop through all of `passedArray`?

Comment: What's wrong right now?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were pretty close; you just need to add a loop to iterate over passedArray.   Comments included in the code below explaining the changes:

```
function drawChart() {
  // you may want to JSON.parse() what you're getting from PHP here:
  var passedArray = <?php echo json_encode($reeco_net); ?>;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
  data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
  let rows = []; // we'll use this to store what you'll pass to addRows
  for (let row of passedArray) { //iterates over the array one row at a time

    // this is a quick way to destructure the row array into your jid, opa, etc variables:
    let [jid, opa, jav, jcd, jre, jno] = [...row];

    // I'm assuming you want to call addRows once; if that fn only accepts one 
    // row at a time you would get rid of the `rows` variable and just 
    // call data.addRows here inside the loop, instead of pushing to `rows`:
    rows.push([{'v':`'${jre}'`, 'f':`${jno}`+ '<a href="hhh.com?thx='+jid+'"><button type="button" style="border:none;background-color: transparent;"><img class="table-avatar circular-square_v" src="../img/avatar/'+jav+'" width="40px" height="40px"></button></a>'}, '', 'toolTip']);
  }

  // now we're outside the loop, pass all that we've gathered to your datable:
  data.addRows(rows);

  // Create the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
  chart.draw(data, {
    'allowHtml': true
  });
}
```